# Using Decision Trees to tune the tree and compare the accuracy rate of several candidate tree models

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
titanic = titanic.drop(['class', 'who', 'adult_male', 'deck', 'embark_town', 'alive', 'alone'], axis=1)
titanic['age'].fillna(titanic.groupby('pclass')['age'].transform("median"), inplace=True)
titanic.dropna(inplace=True)
new_sex = pd.get_dummies(titanic['sex'], drop_first=True)
new_embarked = pd.get_dummies(titanic['embarked'], drop_first=True)
titanic = pd.concat([titanic, new_sex, new_embarked], axis=1)
titanic.drop(['sex', 'embarked'],axis=1, inplace=True)
titanic.head()
X = new_embarked
Y = new_sex
import sklearn 
from sklearn import tree 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
trainX, testX, trainY, testY = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size = 0.3, random_state = 1000)
sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(1,2)
tree1 = tree.fit(trainX, trainY)
print ('the accuracy rate on training data is', titanic.score(trainX, trainY))
print ('the accuracy rate on testing data is', titanic.score(testX, testY))
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(X,Y)
prediction = clf.predict([[169,58,8]])
print = prediction
```

I'm trying to figure out how to make a decision tree that's very basic, then I need to change the depth to a max of two. I'm not looking for someone to do it for me but I just want someone to look at the code and tell me if I'm going in the right direction.

Comment: Did you mean `tree1 = sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(1,2).fit(trainX, trainY)`? Writing `sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(1,2)` on its own will create the tree and immediately destroy it because it's not being assigned to any variable or used anywhere

Comment: Oh awesome thank you I did not even realize that. Do you also know why there might be an error message of AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'score' and     criterion = CRITERIA_CLF[self.criterion](self.n_outputs_,
KeyError: 1

Comment: `titanic.score(trainX, trainY)` should be `tree1.score(trainX, trainY)`

Comment: there's one part of my code still coming up with errors... criterion = CRITERIA_CLF[self.criterion](self.n_outputs_,
KeyError: 1. I added starting at line29 **tree1 = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
tree1_fit = tree1.fit(trainX, trainY)
tree.plot_tree(tree1_fit , filled=True, class_names = ['0','1'] )
tree1 = sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(1,2).fit(trainX, trainY)
print ('the accuracy rate on training data is', tree1.score(trainX, trainY))
print ('the accuracy rate on testing data is', tree1.score(testX, testY))
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(X,Y)**